# Get cumulative length of array inside array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have been searching for quite a while but cannot find an answer to my issue. The problem is pretty simple; I have an array of objects, each containing another array of objects. I want to get the cumulative length of all arrays inside all objects.

Here is some sample data:

```
const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Test 1",
        data: [
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Test 2",
        data: [
            {
                ...
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

In this sample, the length should be 3 since there is 2 objects inside the first object's data property and 1 object inside the second object's data property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty simple

```js
const items =
  [ { id: 1, title: "Test 1", data: [{a:1},{a:1} ] }
  , { id: 2, title: "Test 2", data: [{a:1},{a:1},{a:1},{a:1}] }
  ]
  
console.log('cumulative length ', items.reduce((a,c)=>a+c.data.length,0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop through all items you got, check the length of the `data` array of each item and add that length to a variable. Here is a working snippet:

```js
const items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Test 1",
        data: [
            {
                
            },
            {
                
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Test 2",
        data: [
            {
                
            },
        ]
    }
];
// Initialize the count variable as 0
var count = 0;
// Pass through each item
items.forEach((item)=>{
// Adding the count of data of each item 
  count += item.data.length;
});
// Outputting the count
console.log(count);
```

Comment: You can also do this using `.reduce()` if you want - `items.reduce((acc, cur) => acc += cur.data.length, 0)`

Comment: I would prefer a solution that makes use of the map function or something that doesn’t require a loop. Sorry for not specifying but thanks for the provided solution!

Comment: `.map()` should be used for creating a new Array, not for returning a single output value - If you want a single return value, you should use `.reduce()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use for of loop that works too.

```
const countObjects = (arrayInput) => {
  let totalCount = 0
  for(let item of items) {
    totalCount += item.data.length
  }
  return totalCount
}
console.log(countObjects(items))
```